# Offset from the top changes between the start and end of an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Some context: I'm trying to animate scrolling to a particular element, and I accomplish this by calling the following code from `$(document).ready()`:

```
$('html, body').animate(                                                                      
  // properties                                                                                 
  {
    scrollTop: $("#element").offset().top                                 
  },
  // duration                                                                                   
  500,
  // easing
  "easeOutCubic"
);
```

My problem is that, for some elements, `$("#element").offset().top` will actually change between the time I initiate the animation and the time I make it down to the target element.

My elements are completely static: I perform no DOM manipulation, and I do not resize anything. I specify the sizes in CSS, wait until `$(document).ready()`, and scroll down.

What could I be doing wrong? Am I initiating animation too early, or in the incorrect event handler? Could the act of animation somehow be modifying the positions of my elements?

Possibly relevant points:

- I'm using Google web fonts, and multiple <strike>faces</strike> styles. Perhaps there's some rendering bug?
- I'm running this in Google Chrome. <strike>I have checked and this issue does not manifest itself in Safari</strike>. EDIT: Nope, it happens in Safari too.

Comment: I think that is most likely to be a rendering issue... Especially if you say it doesn't happen on other browsers (better check another one except the two you've mentioned). You can minimize the effects this issue by performing the same command again on the animate `complete handler`.

Comment: there are probably other things happening on document.ready. Things with sizes not defined and still loading: images, ads, iframes. Probably webfonts too (fonts getting bigger/smaller when applied thus causing a reflow)

Comment: After what Robert said, maybe you should consider using setTimeout to delay this event a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into this, and the Chrome timeline inspector reveals that out the fonts are being received *after* the animation is being triggered. This means that the scroll I choose is based on whatever provisional position the target element has *before* the google web fonts are applied.

It's clear that `ready()` is not the place to put this code. My next step will be to figure out where the proper place is.

EDIT:

Turns out the correct place to put this code is in the `load` handler. Moving the code into that method caused this issue to go away.

Comment: good piece of detective work.  You should mark this as the answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

To me it seems like this is the issue that normally occurs when the parent is not relative but the child is absolute. Please see while animating the parent of the element being animated requires to be relative and then if you simply adjust the top/left to animate will cause the effect you need

Comment: Does this issue manifest itself when there is no manipulation of positioning? I've purposefully avoided changing positioning for exactly the reason that it needlessly complicates things.